How to use Azure SDK for C on ESP32 with 4G modem (SIM7670G)?
I have created an application on an ESP32 (S3 Wroom) that uses the Azure SDK for C for provisioning to an IoT Hub using the Device Provisioning Service. Here I used the WiFi connection.
My board is a LilyGo T-SIM7670G and I would like to change my application to access the Internet using the modem (SIM7670G) instead. Wifi is not an option where it is going to run.
I successfully got an IP address from the modem connection, where I used TinyGsm.
My problem is, how do I configure the azure_iot_config to use the modem connection, and not the Wifi?
Here is my code:
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "mqtt_interface.h"
#include "ntp_timesync.h"
#include "web_server.h"
#include "gsm_modem.h"
#include "esp_netif.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_modem.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

static const char *wifi_ssid = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_SSID;
static const char *wifi_password = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_PASSWORD;
static const char *wifi_ap_ssid = IOT_CONFIG_AP_WIFI_SSID;
static const char *wifi_ap_password = IOT_CONFIG_AP_WIFI_PASSWORD;

static bool azure_initial_connect = false; // Turns true when ESP32 successfully connects to Azure IoT Central for the first time
static unsigned long next_telemetry_send_time_ms = 0;
static unsigned long next_wifi_reconnect_time_ms = 0;
static unsigned int best_ap_channel = -1;

static bool WifiConnectionOk = false;
static bool ModemConnectionOk = false;
static int AzureStatus = 0;
static bool WifiFirstActivation = false;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_LOGGER_BAUD_RATE);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_APSTA);
    WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);

    reconnect_wifi();

    // Start GSM modem
    ModemConnectionOk = initialize_modem();
    if (ModemConnectionOk)
    {
        Serial.println("Modem initialized");
        getTimeFromModem();
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Modem not connecting to network");
        ModemConnectionOk = false;
    }

    // Setup access point, and the webserver
    setup_wifi_ap();
    initialize_webserver();

    if (WifiConnectionOk || ModemConnectionOk)
    {
        configure_azure_iot();
        azure_iot_start(&azure_iot);
    }
}

void loop()
{
    server.handleClient();
    if (!WifiConnectionOk)
    {
        if (millis() > next_wifi_reconnect_time_ms)
        {
            azure_iot_stop(&azure_iot);
            reconnect_wifi();
            next_wifi_reconnect_time_ms = millis() + WIFI_RECONNECT_INTERVAL_MILLISECS;

            if (!azure_initial_connect)
            {
                configure_azure_iot();
            }
            azure_iot_start(&azure_iot);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!WifiFirstActivation)
        {
            //First time the wifi goes online, perform NTP operation
            sync_device_clock_with_ntp_server();
            WifiFirstActivation = true;
        }
    }

    int current_status = azure_iot_get_status(&azure_iot);
    switch (current_status)
    {
        case azure_iot_connecting:
        if (AzureStatus != current_status)
        {
            Serial.println("Azure is connecting ...");
        }
        break;

        case azure_iot_connected:
        if (AzureStatus != current_status)
        {
            Serial.println("Azure is connected!");
            azure_initial_connect = true;
        }
        break;

        case azure_iot_error:
        if (AzureStatus != current_status)
        {
            Serial.println("Azure IoT client is in error state.");
            azure_iot_stop(&azure_iot);
        }
        break;

        default:
        if (AzureStatus != current_status)
        {
            Serial.print("Unknown azure respose: ");
            Serial.println(current_status);
        }
        break;
    }

    AzureStatus = current_status;

    if (millis() > next_telemetry_send_time_ms)
    {
        sendTelemetry(&azure_iot);
        next_telemetry_send_time_ms = millis() + TELEMETRY_FREQUENCY_MILLISECS;
    }

    azure_iot_do_work(&azure_iot);
    delay(10);
}

static void reconnect_wifi()
{
    Serial.println("WiFi reconnect");
    WiFi.disconnect();
    delay(250);
    connect_to_wifi();
}

static void connect_to_wifi()
{
    Serial.print("Connecting to WIFI wifi_ssid: ");
    Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
    WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event)
{
    Serial.printf("[WiFi-event] event: %d\n", event);
    switch (event)
    {
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
        Serial.println("WiFi connected");
        Serial.println("IP address: ");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        WifiConnectionOk = true;
        break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
        Serial.println("WiFi lost connection");
        WifiConnectionOk = false;
        break;
    }
}

The Azure part is a copy of the sample in:
github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main/examples/… –
As far as I understand, that right strategy would be to use netif to register the SIM7670G modem network interface.
Unfortunately, I lack the skills to implement this.
Are there anyone that can help?
I have studied the netif documentation, but it requires quite deep knowledge and I have been unsuccessful in getting anything to work.
The current implementation of the modem is using the TinyGsm framework, but I have found this incompatible with the netif configuration.

Please share the code of Azure SDK for C with Azure IoT in the question above.

The Azure SDK part is copied from this sample : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/tree/main/examples/Azure_IoT_Central_ESP32

Everything runs fine, when I enable Wifi connection, so the Azure part is ok.
Modem is initialized with:
SerialAT.begin(SERIAL_AT_BAUD_RATE, SERIAL_8N1, MODEM_RX_PIN, MODEM_TX_PIN);
TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
Network registraton also works, and I also retrieve time from NTP server, using the modem connection.
